# Extract words from a string, creating a variable according to their exact order in the string

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, loops

I would like to print one or more words of "keywords" contained in text.

I would like to print them in the exact order they are written. So `var1` will be Python, `var2` will be Java, `var3` will be Rust. I need to be able to handle these variables individually and separately. Maybe I need `split()`, not like this

If I try to print `x`, I get `Java, Python, Rust` (they're not in order)

I need `Python, Java, Rust`, and the exact order should set automatically

How can i get this?

```
text     = "My favorite languages are Python and Java. I like less Rust"
keywords = ["C#", "JAVA", "PHP", "PYTHON", "RUST", "JAVASCRIPT"] 

matches  = [x for x in keywords if x in text.upper()]

for x in matches:
    print("test x: ", x) #Java, Python, Rust
    var1= x
    var2= x
    var3= x

print(var1)
print(var2)
print(var3)
```

Comment: Use `matches  = [(text.upper().find(x), x) for x in keywords if x in text.upper()]`, sort `matches` and extract the keywords from the result. This can be written more efficiently but should work.

Comment: This answer to this question gets slightly more complicated as they want to find both `JAVA` and `JAVASCRIPT` - whenever `JAVASCRIPT` is found, `JAVA` will be found as well since it is a substring of the former.

Comment: How you don't appreciate volunteer's time and effort is incredible. The way to hardcode `var1`, `var2`, etc is useless and bad for maintainance. You could take a list of keywords and access via `kewyords[0]`, `keywords[1]` etc. instead. If you are not accustomed to `0, 1, ...` yet, do: `keywords[1-1]`, `keywords[2-1]`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a small concise and foldable script while trying to preserve a dynamic side.

```
import re

text     = "My favorite languages are Python and Java. I like less Rust and Javascript and my Python is a little rusty"
keywords = ["C#", "JAVA", "PHP", "PYTHON", "JAVASCRIPT", "RUST"]


j = '|'.join(keywords)

r = re.compile(rf'\b({j})\b', re.IGNORECASE)
matches = r.findall(text)

d = dict()

for i, m in enumerate(matches):
    # if m not in d.values(): # To avoid duplicates, uncomment this line and indent the next one
    d["var_" + str(i)] = m   

for k, v in d.items():
    print(f'{k} = {v}')
```

Prints out

```
var_0 = Python
var_1 = Java
var_2 = Rust
var_3 = Javascript
var_4 = Python
```

Answer (score 0):

I think regular expression are the best way to go.

```
import re

text     = "My favorite languages are Python and Java. I like less Rust. Python meh"
keywords = ["C#", "JAVA", "PHP", "PYTHON", "JAVASCRIPT"]

regex = re.compile(r'|'.join(keywords), re.IGNORECASE)
print(regex.findall(text))
```

Output:

```
['Python', 'Java', 'Python']
```

This will print python twice, you hadn't specified if that is desired behaviour.

Comment: You wrote print(regex.findall(text)), but how can I get the variables var1, var2 and var3 individually? Thank you

Comment: @aesh unless you have a very good reason to do that, you should keep your data in a list . And having your variables named `var1` and so on is a sure sign that you need a list.

Comment: I had the same idea using `re` module :D. - yes, if you hardcode `var1`, `var2`, etc. - it i better to use a list - because then, you can add more words - without the need to change any code later.

Comment: @aesh this answer is already exactly what I wanted to do.

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim I need to extract the variables var1, var2, var3. How can I extract these variables from regex.findall(text)?

Comment: @aesh - what you mean with 'extract' the variables - as given in text or as given in the keywaords list (all upper case)?

Comment: @Gwang-JinKim As indicated in the text. I would like var1 to be Python, var2 to be Java, var3 to be Rust. I need to be able to handle these variables individually and separately, extracting them from regex.findall(text). Maybe I need split(), not like this. Can you show me how to do it? Thank you

Comment: Your code would find "rust" in "rusty"...

Answer (score 0):

Trying to keep my solution as similar as possible to yours, I think this is the best way (OFC not using other libraries).

```py
text     = "My favorite languages are Python and Java. I like less Rust."
keywords = ["C#", "JAVA", "PHP", "PYTHON", "JAVASCRIPT", "RUST"] 

# Normalize text with no "stops"
text = text.replace(".", "")

# Split Upper Text
text = text.upper().split()

# Iterate through Tw and if found in Kw append
matched = []
for w in text:
    for k in keywords:
        if w == k:
            matched.append(k)

var1, var2, var3 = matched
print(var1, var2, var3, sep="\n")
```

If you want to create "dynamic vars" I don't think you can, you must declare them.
For this reason, it's better to have a list, and access/iterate to the value you need, when you need it.

I hope to have helped you

Edit:
It's possible to assign variables dynamically but it's not a "good to use"

```py
vars = [f"var{i} ='{v}'" for i,v in enumerate(matched)]
for e in vars:
    exec(e)

print(var1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since perfect match is searched for, I suggest a solution without `re`.
Though `re` is standard library - therefore one should use it.

```
class MyContainer:
    def __init__(self, keywords, ignore_case=True, remove_signs=True, return_key=False):
        self._keywords = keywords      # keep original input
        self.ignore_case = ignore_case
        self.remove_signs = remove_signs
        self.keywords = [self.prepare(x) for x in keywords]
        self.return_key = return_key
        self._keydict = {k: v for k, v in zip(self.keywords, self._keywords)}
    
    def __contains__(self, x):
        return self.prepare(x) in self.keywords
    
    def remove_sign(self, x):
        return x.rstrip("!.?;,- \t\"\'")
    
    def prepare(self, x):
        if self.ignore_case:
            x = x.lower()
        if self.remove_signs:
            x = self.remove_sign(x)
        return x
    
    def findall(self, s):
        return [x if not self.return_key else self._keydict[self.prepare(x)] for x in s.split() if x in self]

# return what was found in text
kws = MyContainer(keywords, ignore_case=True, remove_signs=True, return_key=False)
kws.findall(text) 
## ['Python', 'Java.', 'Python']


# return as given in keywords
kws = MyContainer(keywords, ignore_case=True, remove_signs=True, return_key=True)
kws.findall(text) 
## ['PYTHON', 'JAVA', 'PYTHON']
```

Using the `__init__` method, you can pre-prepare your keywords list depending on `ignore_case` and `remove_signs`.
the `__contains__` dunder method is for easy use via the `in` operator.

With the flag arguments `ignore_case`, `remove_signs`, `return_key`, you can determine whether case should be ignored, signs at the right end removed and whether the word should be given as found in text or as specified in keywords, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

To your `var1`, `var2`, etc. problem, use multi-assignment in Python via destructuring:

```
var1, var2, var3 = matches
```

If you want to print them out:

```
for i, x in enumerate(matches):
    print(f"var{i} = {x}")
```